# Paypal IPN listener code hanging/not responding

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using the 'textbook' IPN script example as found on the paypal website. However, when running this code via the IPN simulator, there is a huge loading time and then PayPal throws this error:

> ```
> Proxy Error
> ```
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request POST
>   /webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

Here is my IPN listener code.

Would much appreciate some help!

```
        // Send an empty HTTP 200 OK response to acknowledge receipt of the notification
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

        // Assign payment notification values to local variables
        $item_name        = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number      = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id           = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email   = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'];
        $job_id           = $_POST['custom'];

        // Build the required acknowledgement message out of the notification just received
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               // Add 'cmd=_notify-validate' to beginning of the acknowledgement

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         // Loop through the notification NV pairs
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode these values
            $req  .= "&$key=$value";                   // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
        }

        // Set up the acknowledgement request headers
        $header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";                    // HTTP POST request
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

        // Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        // Send the HTTP POST request back to PayPal for validation
        fputs($fp, $header . $req);

        while (!feof($fp)) {                     // While not EOF
            $res = fgets($fp, 1024);               // Get the acknowledgement response
            $message = 'fail';
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  // Response contains VERIFIED - process notification


                // Possible processing steps for a payment include the following:

                $job = $this->jobmodel->get_by_id($job_id);

                // Process payment
                $this->jobmodel->add_payment($job_id, $_POST);
                $message = $job_id;

            }
            else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

                // Authentication protocol is complete - begin error handling

                $message = 'fail';

            }


            $filename = 'Paypal IPN' . date('d-m-Y g-i', mktime());
            $myFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/assets/html/paypal/$filename.html";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            fwrite($fh, $message);
            fclose($fh);

        }

        fclose($fp);  // Close the file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not sending a 'Host' header along in your IPN verification request, and your script doesn't appear to be able to handle HTTP chunked data.
I would suggest starting with [this](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php) example and working from there.

```
<?php

// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);

// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);


define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");


// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;

} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

            // Split response headers and payload
            list($headers, $res) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $res, 2);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}

// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try it out and come back with an update.